# Passing values to Javascript functions

Tags: javascript

Is A or B better and why?

A) var myvar = this.value();
   myFunc(myvar);

B) myFunc(this.value());

Comment: B is better because it is shorter.

Comment: B is better because it is better readable and less sensitive for errors like variable shadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` is better because you don't pollute the current function's scope with a *one shot* variable. However you should be able to figure out these things by yourself.

Also, as others pointed out, it's 2 line vs 1 line of code. Not such a dramatic improvement, but still...

Answer (score 0):

If `myvar` is used only one time, then `B` is short and clean.

If `myvar` need to be used for many times, then it is better to save `this.value()` to the local variable, `A` is better.

Answer (score 0):

B is better because it will save the memory of allocating variable myVar. Further the code is much cleaner in B.